# Why negation is not working here?

Tags: java, regex

```
String text = "$.example(\"This is the tes't\")";
final String quoteRegex = "example.*?(\"[^is].*?\")";
Matcher matcher0 = Pattern.compile(quoteRegex).matcher(text);
while (matcher0.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher0.group(1));
}
```

It returns `This is the tes't`.  I was expecting not to return any result because of negation `[^is]`   which says do not match `is`. Then why
it is returning `This is the tes't` ?

Similarly `example.*?(\".*?\")` regex returns `This is the tes't` but `example(\".*?\")` does not why ?

Comment: [Only ask a single question per question, click this text to find out why.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^is]` does not say do not match `is`, it says match a character that is not `i` or `s`, and your example has `T` after the `"` so it matches.

If you want to match zero or more characters and exclude the string `"is"`, you can do:

```
example.*?(\"(?:(?!is).)*?\")
```

If you only want to not match `is` immediately after the `"` (which is *not* what your example has):

```
example.*?(\"(?!is).*?\")
```

You also ask why `example(\".*?\")` does not match; that regex only matches if there is a `"` immediately after `example`, while your example has a `(` between.  You could match the `(` but still capture the quoted string with:

```
example\((\"...
```

Comment: What if i need to check string `is` not immediately after quote `"` ?

Comment: Also can you please answer second part in my question `Similarly example.*?(\".*?\") regex returns This is the tes't but example(\".*?\") does not why ?` ?